# Simple sub query?

Tags: php, mysql

John       5555

Nancy      5555

Joe        2323

I need an example of a simple query to do the following so I can figure out how to 
apply it to another query. thx.

```
 Search for "John"
 Returns rows John, Nancy

 Search for "Nancy"
 Returns rows John, Nancy

 Search for "Joe"
 Returns rows Joe
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect," SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE name like '%$search%'
   (   SELECT number 
      FROM users
      WHERE number like number )
ORDER BY date ASC");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Assume your `table` columns are *name* and *number*.

```
name  |  number
John  |   5555
Nancy |   5555
Joe   |   2323
```

And here's the code:

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$connection=mysqli_connect("YourHost","Username","Password","DatabaseName");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['submitsearch'])){ /* IF FORM IS SUBMITTED */
   $searchname=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['search']); /* PREVENT SOME OF THE SQL INJECTIONS */
   $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='$searchname'");
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $number=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$row['number']); /* GET THE RESPECTIVE NUMBER OF THE SEARCHED NAME */
   }


   /* ECHO THE RESULT HERE */
   echo "<table>";
   $result2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE number='$number'");
   while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ /* FETCH ROWS WITH THE SAME NUMBER COLUMN */
   echo "<tr><td>".$row2['name']."</td></tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";

}

/* THIS IS YOUR HTML FORM */

echo "<form action='' method='POST'>"; /* SUBMIT ON THE SAME PAGE */
echo "search:<input type='text' name='search'>";
echo "<input type='text' value='search' name='submitsearch'>";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can click the accept button on my answer:)

Answer (score 0):

If I don't miss your requirement, your sql statement should be like this:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' 
OR number IN(SELECT number FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%$search%') 
ORDER BY Date ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
```

Hope this help you.